# Facebook dialog width is hidden

Tags: facebook, fbdialogs

I am having issue with fb.ui method feeds. It seems that 30% of the popup dialog width is hidden by the sponsored/advertisement panel. I know there is a way to specify the width and height for the popup, but I would rather have the option to be on the top z-index 2000 or something like that. How can I do that?

Here is a screenshot of it!

[image]

Comment: cool..there is someone that minus a point from the question...wonder if he/she could explain why.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using CSS.  The Facebook dialog is a collection of div's wrapping an iFrame.  By leveraging the !important attribute of CSS, I was able to control the size of my dialog boxes.

```
.fb_dialog, .fb_dialog_iframe iframe { width: 400px !important; }
```

Of course, you should set the width values to something appropriate for your application.